# control android system camera to capture

Tags: android, camera

I build one app and open the system camera app by it.My app has a service running in the background and I want the service send a message to control the system camera capturing pictures at any time I want.
But now I do not know how to control system camera app capture through my app,could you please help me?Thanks a lot!

I use this method to open system camera app:

```
    public static void openCLD(String packageName,Context context) { 
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager(); 

    Intent resolveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null); 
    resolveIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
    resolveIntent.setPackage(packageName); 

    List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(resolveIntent, 0); 

    ResolveInfo ri = apps.iterator().next(); 
    if (ri != null ) { 
        String className = ri.activityInfo.name; 

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) ; 

        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className); 

        intent.setComponent(cn); 
        context.startActivity(intent); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which **packageName** do you pass to this function?

Comment: Different phone's camera packageName is different ,so I used the method below to get camera app's packageName: getCameraPackage(){
  String str = null;
        ResolveInfo res;
        Intent infoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        res = this.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(infoIntent, 0);
        if (res != null) {
         str = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        }
        return str;
 }

Comment: OK, now I understand your wish. No, unfortunately the AOSP Camera app does not publish a way to capture a picture without user action. Note that the Camera app installed on actual device may be very different, and even though they are expected to serve same Intents (like MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), there are painful variations.

Comment: OK，thank you very much!   What a pity~At first I want to create my own camera app but there are too many different android devices.I don't have enough time adapting all the devices.